# Read facts from file

Tags: prolog

I have words like weather, wind etc.

And I try to make a fact from these words.

attributes(weather, wind)

Do you hava any idea?

Thank a lot

Comment: What did you try so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I read words from file, and I try to write another file facts.

Comment: And what kind of facts does your program need?

Comment: I cant make a fact. Because I dont know all words, I read all words from file. x.txt and I try to write another file x.py

Comment: My program doesnt need to fact. My program try to make these facts.

Comment: You probably need `assert`. What does your input look like?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `assert/2`, but it's hard to tell how exactly you should use it without knowing what kind of facts you need.

If you can read atoms from a file, you can assert there one-by-one into `fact/1` terms with:

```
assert_from_stream(Stream) :-
    read(Stream, X),
    assert(fact(X)).
```

Be sure to declare `fact/1` (or whatever you use to store facts) with

```
:- dynamic fact/1.
```

Facts with more than one argument work in the same way: `assert(attributes(weather, wind))` after declaring `dynamic attributes/2`.